# IIS / ASP.NET MVC - Allowing Large File Uploads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I'm trying to configure my ASP.NET MVC web application to allow file uploads up to 350MB. I'm on IIS7.

I've tried the following Web.config changes:

Adding the below under **system.web**

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2097151" executionTimeout="270" />
```

I've also tried this **system.webserver**

```
 <system.webServer>
      <security>
          <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="367001600"/>
          </requestFiltering>
      </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

For both of these, I still see HTTP 404 13 issues in my server logs (file too large), and I see a 404 in my browser.

Is there any other setting that affects large file uploads?

Comment: Just to clarify... Did you use both settings at the same time?

Comment: Try them both at the same time.

Comment: I did, and I get the same issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out ? Having the same issue.